# ASP NET Entity Framework primary key Duplicate resolution

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        Articles article = new Articles();
        return View(article);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Articles article)
    {
        try
        {
            article.ViewCount = 0;
            article.IPAddress = Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
            article.RegistDate = DateTime.Now;
            article.RegistMemberID = "admin";
            article.ModifyDate = DateTime.Now;
            article.ModifyMemberID = "admin";


            db.Articles.Add(article);
            db.SaveChanges();

            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var attachFile = Request.Files[0];

                if (attachFile != null && attachFile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(attachFile.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Upload/"), fileName);
                    attachFile.SaveAs(path);

                    ArticleFiles file = new ArticleFiles();
                    file.ArticleIDX = article.ArticleIDX;
                    file.FilePath = "/Upload/";
                    file.FileName = fileName;
                    file.FileFormat = Path.GetExtension(attachFile.FileName);
                    file.FileSize = attachFile.ContentLength;
                    file.UploadDate = DateTime.Now;

                    db.ArticleFiles.Add(file);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }

            ViewBag.Result = "OK";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Board");
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            ViewBag.Result = "FAIL";
        }


        return View(article);
        //return RedirectToAction("ArticleList");
    }
```

The controller writes a message. But if you write a message (through a POST request) on a bulletin board, it will work normally when you try to post it the first time. But when you try to post again, it fails. I think the cause is a duplicate primary key.
Please let me know what you can do in case of a duplication of the primary key.

```
    namespace HeadHomePage1.Models
    {
        public class ArticlesEditViewModel
        {

            public Articles Article { get; set; }

            public List<ArticleFiles> Files { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

모델부분입니다.

Comment: What's the primary key in your table and how are you generating its value?

Comment: The primary key of the table is ArticleIDX.
It does not accept the primary key.